# MPAndroidChart -Use multiple text instead of "No Chart Data available" depends on the data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

I tried to **change MPAndroid Chart text of  "No Chart Data available" into "Loading Data..."** while the data is retrieving.I had done this.But when there is no data the chart layout should shows ," NO DATA".

I am getting the Same Text(Loading Data...) eventhough there is no data.

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     if (!mDataNotSet && mData==null) {
     canvas.drawText("NO DATA", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 3, mInfoPaint);
     return;
} 

if (mDataNotSet && mData == null || mData.getYValCount() <= 0) {
 canvas.drawText"Laoding Data...",getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mInfoPaint);

     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mNoDataTextDescription))
     {
     float textOffset = -mInfoPaint.ascent() + mInfoPaint.descent();
     canvas.drawText(mNoDataTextDescription, getWidth()/2,(getHeight() / 2)
                            + textOffset, mInfoPaint);
                }
     return;
            }
     if (!mOffsetsCalculated) {
       calculateOffsets();
                mOffsetsCalculated = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I made the modification in Chart Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change it as below ,

```
LineChart mChart;

mChart.setDescription("");

mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");

mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("Your message");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setNoDataText` method to set the message back to whatever text you want once data loading is done.

So when data load is started, run

```
chart.setNoDataText("Loading Data...");
```

After data load is done

```
 chart.setNoDataText("NO DATA");
```

Comment: Thank you... For plotting graph I need to get a sales amount of particular shop.So I used  if ...else   in Fragment that I used for plotting charts                                                                             if (strAmount.equals("0")) {
            mChart.setNoDataText("NO DATA");
        } else {
            mChart.setNoDataText("Loading Data from Server... ");
        }