# How to change text when data is not available on MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPAndroidChart` to draw some charts on my `Android` application and I would like to change the default message that appears when the data is not available.

I am using a `CombinedChart` and a `BarChart` and in none of them I am able to change the text when data is not available.

I know that there are few questions on Stackoverflow related with this theme. For example:

- [MPAndroidChart - Change message "No chart data available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892275/mpandroidchart-change-message-no-chart-data-available)
- [MPAndroidChart -Use multiple text instead of "No Chart Data available" depends on the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648516/mpandroidchart-use-multiple-text-instead-of-no-chart-data-available-depends-o)

but all of them make reference to one or more of these methods:

```
.setDescription("");
.setNoDataTextDescription("Custom message.");
.setNoDataTextDescription("Custom message");
.setNoDataText("Custom message");
```

Any of them worked for me.

My snippet of code in which I try to change the text is the following:

```
combinedChart.setDescription(null);
combinedChart.setNoDataText("No data");

combinedChart.setData(data);
combinedChart.animateXY(2500,2500);
```

How can I provide a different text message to the user when data is not available?

**EDIT:** I have added `.invalidate` method as @SudhakarRaju suggested but it also does not work. My actual code is:

```
combinedChart.setDescription(null);
combinedChart.setNoDataText("No data");
combinedChart.setNoDataTextDescription("No data");
combinedChart.setNoDataTextDescription("No data");

combinedChart.invalidate();
combinedChart.setData(data);
combinedChart.animateXY(2500,2500);
//I also tried to put combinedChart.invalidate(); here but it also does not work.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The same way above you mentioned but you have to add one extra line. `combinedChart.invalidate();` This will work.

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to style the chart if no data:

```
            mChart.setNoDataText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_data_available));
            mChart.setNoDataTextColor(BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.black));

            // from: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/89
            Paint p = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
            if (p != null) {
                p.setTextSize(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.no_data_text_size));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `combinedChart.setData(data)` call.

For some reason, if you send an empty Data object that contains an empty data set, the "no data" text will not be displayed.

I had the same problem and I resolved it by simply not setting the data if it's empty, or using `combinedChart.clear()` for that matter.